# Block DNS traffic except for 1 device

Tags: iptables

Good evening all. I want to block outbound DNS traffic from all of my devices except the pihole (192.168.2.196).

Im thinking the following iptables rules should work but I'm inexperienced with iptables so I'm hoping someone can help me before I try it and make my wife mad because the internet doesn't work anymore.

```
iptables -A OUTBOUND -p UDP -s 192.168.2.196 --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTBOUND -p TCP -s 192.168.2.196 --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTBOUND -s 192.168.2.1/24 --dport 53 -j DROP
```

Additionally some of the devices like Google home are hard coded to use 8.8.8.8 as their DNS so I was thinking something like this to redirect them to the pihole?

```
iptables -A OUTBOUND -d 8.8.8.8/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.196
iptables -A OUTBOUND -d 8.8.8.8/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.196
iptables -A OUTBOUND -d 8.8.4.4/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.196
iptables -A OUTBOUND -d 8.8.4.4/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.196
```

Does anyone see any of these issues with these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I wound up using the following two iptables inputs to redirect all DNS traffic to my DNS server instead of straight blocking it. This allows devices with hard coded DNS addresses to still function (albeit a bit slower)

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i br0 -p udp ! --source 192.168.2.196 ! --destination 192.168.2.196 --dport 53 -j DNAT --to 192.168.2.196

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i br0 -p tcp ! --source 192.168.2.196 ! --destination 192.168.2.196 --dport 53 -j DNAT --to 192.168.2.196
```

Where 192.168.2.196 is the IP address of my DNS server.